# correctly batch run chain of SoX commands step by step - issues

Tags: windows, batch-file, sox

For all .wav files in sox-14-4-2 folder I need to remove silence at start, copy the result into an existing subfolder **Output**, then reverse the file, remove silence again and finally reverse again.

The first silence remove task is unproblematic:

```
FOR %%A IN (*.wav) do (
 sox %%A "Output\%%~nxa" silence 1 0.1 1%
 )
```

Somehow I can't imagine how to execute 3 more sox commands one by one for each .wav file in **Output** folder after this?

```
FOR %%A IN ("Output\sample1.wav") DO (
sox %%A "Output\%%~nxa.wav" reverse
)
```

Here for the second sox command **reverse**, one general problem is that I don't know how to apply this to all .wav files in the **Output** folder?
`FOR %%A ("Output\*.wav")` is wrong

Second SoX specific issue here is that I can't use the same name - I can't use **%%~nxa**, instead I need to create a new file with a new name or output will be broken with *Premature EOF on .wav output file* in **Output** folder and it will become 80 bytes.

How do I solve this and apply 4 SoX commands in order on all .wav files?
The finished .wav files should be located in a subfolder **Output** after all tasks are done with original input filename, also keep all input files in the folder above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like SoX requires some special handling when it works with uncompressed files.
While writing output SoX need the uncompressed input file still open, so forcing replace in this case will always cause *Premature EOF on .wav output file* error.

```
for %%a in (*.wav) do copy /y *.wav *.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.wav) do (
  if not exist "%%~dpaTemporalOutput\" md "%%~dpaTemporalOutput\"
  if not exist "%%~dpaOutput\" md "%%~dpaOutput\"
  "sox.exe" "%%~dpa%%~xna" "%%~dpaTemporalOutput\%%~xna" OUR 2 SOX COMMANDS HERE
  "sox.exe" "TemporalOutput\%%~xna" "%%~xna" SAME 2 SOX COMMANDS HERE )
del /f /q "TemporalOutput\*.wav"
rmdir /s /q "TemporalOutput"
move "*.wav" "Output\"
ren *. *.wav
exit /b
```